# Calculating DateTime display for different time zones, for a world clock

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am working on a small C# / ASP.NET project that will display 4 or 5 different labels to show what time it is in different parts of the world.

I have been researching tons of different questions and blog posts about this across the net but I'm still missing a few pieces that a more experienced developer could fill in no problem.  I have read up on things like "TimeZoneInfo" and "ToLocalTime" and "GetUTCOffSet" and the like.. and to someone as new as me it is getting confusing.  I must say most of this info I have seen right here on Stack Overflow.  I'd like to show what I have currently and see if I could get some advice here:

Code behind:

```
        protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string militaryTime = ( "HH:mm:ss tt" );
        lblTimer1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(militaryTime);
    }
```

Mark up on the .aspx page:

```
     <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="1000">
                </asp:Timer>
                <h4 style="width: 200px">
                    Local :&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblTimer1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </h4>
```

Now, I understand that this is probably going to make more sense to do client side in Javascript, but this task is also a learning tool on how to make this happen in C# without the JS.

Anyway, I'm having trouble figuring out how to display different time zones for the following 4 labels I have.  I want it to work off of DateTimeNow because this could be seen anywhere in the world in any time zone, and it should update the other 4 labels representing different world cities based on the users time zone in relation to those cities.

Again, I understand there are a lot of threads out there about this, and as you read this I am researching them, but so far I'm still missing some of the basic structure I need to build from.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should take a look at the [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) structure and the [noda-time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) project.

Comment: @DanielA.White hahaha he must be busy in other section. gotta love that guy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx)

*The DateTimeOffset structure includes a DateTime value, together with an Offset property that defines the difference between the current DateTimeOffset instance's date and time and Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).*